# Getting location android?

Tags: java, android, database, performance, optimization

I want to receive location updates every second for a small period of time, so I wrote this code:

```
     public void registerListener() {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(c, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(c, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            } else {
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, locationListener);
            }
        }
        private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                 longitude = location.getLongitude();
                 latitude = location.getLatitude();

                Log.v(TAG, ""+longitude + "                       " +latitude);

            }
@Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {} 
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {} 
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    };
```

I call `registerListener()` from somewhere else. The problem is, my location update is only called once, and I only get that log once. Also, the log only comes about 5-10 seconds **after** calling `registerListener`.

### What is the reason of the slowness, and why isn't the location being updated?

Thanks,

Ruchir

Comment: You have the min distance set to 10 meters

Comment: @Ruchir Baronia try using FusedLocation API it good and latest refer here:-  http://coderzpassion.com/android-location-using-google-play-services/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're requesting GPS location.  It will take a few seconds to get a satellite lock for the first time.  It may never happen if you can't receive a signal lock (indoors in some buildings, too far underground, physical damage to the phone like a loose antenna (common in early gen Samsungs)).

As for not receiving it again-  you won't receive it again unless you move at least 10 meters.  Change that to 0 and see it come every second.

Comment: Thanks Gabe. I had a question on the initial GPS time. It takes too long for my app. Is there anything I can do to reduce this time?

Comment: Also, what does the second parameter signify? The `1000`.

Comment: The second parameter is the minimum time between updates.  So if you use 1000, it will update you at most once per second.

Comment: As for reducing time-  not much.  It literally has to send a signal to outer space.  THat takes time.  You can call getLastKnownLocation and see if its not null, and if so use that as an initial value, just don't depend on it being there.  Depending on your app you may be able to turn on updates earlier, but it will take time whenever you start the process.

Comment: Oh, okay. So If I set it to a really long number, like two days, then even _if_ I move 10 meters within the frame of those two days, I wouldn't be notified, because the time overrules the distance, right?

Comment: And for your second comment, is there any way to see how long that will take? Or maybe show a spinning dialog to the user _untill_ I get that data? Because I know I cant speed up the signal, but I can make the user wait.

Comment: That way I can prompt the user to wait, something like: "Fetching location, please wait"

Comment: There's no way of knowing.  There's 20 something GPS satellites, it needs to get a strong enough signal to at least... I think 7 of them?  Not all of which are visible at any one time because they orbit the earth.  And it has all the problems of any long distance radio-  if something blocks line of site it may or may not be able to send a signal through it.  You're best off putting up an indeterminate progress bar.

Comment: And yes, it uses the AND of the distance and time requirements.  So if you set it to 2 days, you could fly to Europe and it wouldn't fire.

Comment: Hey, so although I can't show a progress bar, I am thinking of showing a generic loading screen untill I stop getting 0 for the latitude and longitude. Here is my question:

Comment: "a few seconds"? For GPS? Even now (years later) a GPS fix without additional "tricks" can take several minutes. Indoors GPS only works under optimal conditions.